# How to freeze the order of interaction terms in update.formula

Tags: r, model, statistics, formula, interaction

I want to keep the interaction term at the beginning of my formula statement after I have used `update.formula`. 
This is what happens when I type:

```
update.formula(Y ~ a:b + a + b, ~ . + z)
 > Y ~ a + b + z + a:b
```

What I want is:

```
update.formula(Y ~ a:b + a + b, ~ . + z)
 > Y ~ a:b + a + b + z
```

I know of the `keep.order = TRUE` option in `terms.formula` but that does not work in combination with `update.formula` .

Thanks in advance for your great ideas.

Best, Martijn

Comment: Wow! This seems like a bug, because the documentation says that `terms.formula(keep.order=T)` should keep order. Interested to see the answer.

Comment: `update.formula <- function (old, new, ...) 
{
    tmp <- .Call(C_updateform, as.formula(old), as.formula(new))
    out <- formula(terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE))
    return(out)
}`. It does not have `keep.order = TRUE` in the `terms.formula()` call.

Comment: It's not a bug. As pointed out, the `update.formula` function doesn't have a `keep.order` argument in the `terms.formula` function that it calls. Why? Probably because the R gurus thought it wasn't important to keep the order of the terms, or the original `terms.formula` function didn't have a `keep.order` argument when it was written, and as often the case, other functions that call it weren't updated when the argument was added, or ... who knows?

Comment: Pity that it is not implemented. Seems that I have to challenge myself to find a solution. Thanks anyway!